# Quotient Space $X^*$ is homeomorphic to the Subspace $S^2$ of $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

> > Let $X$ be the closed unit ball $\{ x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \}$ in $\mathbb R^2$ and let $X^*$ be the partition of $X$ consisitingof all the one point set $\{ x \times y \}$ for which $x^2 + y^2 < 1$, along with the set $S^1 = \{ x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}$. Let $p : X \rightarrow X^*$ be the surjective map carry each point of $X$ to the element of $X^*$ containg it. A topology $\tau_p$ defined on $X^*$ induced by $p$ such that a subset $U$ of $X^*$ is open if $P^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$ ; then $(X^*, \tau_p)$ is called Quotien Space of $X$ induced by $p$.
> >
> > What are the saturated open sets of $X$, where saturated set is a subset of $X$ with respect to $p$ if it is the form $P^{-1}(U)$, where $U \subset X^*$

I think open saturated subsets of x are $\{ (x,y) | r < x^2 
+ y^2 \leq 1 \}$, where $ 0 < r <1$ and open balls contained in $X$.

> > what are the open subsets of $X^*$. Also show that $X^*$ is homeomorphic to the subspace  $ S^2 = \{ (x,y,z) | x^2 + y^2 +z^2 = 1\}$ of $\mathbb R^3$

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Let $Y_1=B^2\left(\left(-0,5;0\right);0,1\right), \ Y_2=B^2\left(\left(0,5;0\right);0,1\right)$. Then $p^{-1}p\left(Y_1 \cup Y_2\right)=Y_2\cup Y_2$. Hence also $Y_1\cup Y_2$ is a open saturated set.

Comment: I am not understanding, what do you want to say

Comment: There are other open saturated subsets of $X$. For example $Y_1\cup Y_2$ is open saturated subset of $X$, but it is neither open ball nor set of a form $\{r<x^2+y^2 \le 1\}$.